# Laravel - Query Buider - SQL fields using LPAD statement

Tags: php, sql, laravel, builder, lpad

I'm cannot retry this query, in QueryBuilder:

`select id, lpad(number, 12, 0), lpad(int, 2, 0) from users;`

How I can, in the example not function...

`DB::table('users') ->select('id', 'lpad(number, 12, 0)', 'lpad(int, 2, 0)' ->get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `selectRaw`.

```
DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('id, lpad(number, 12, 0), lpad(int, 2, 0)')
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw

Comment: Thank's @MichalOravec, your answer helped me.